# Building ActionScript 3.0 apps without Flash Builder

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I have an Actionscript 3.0 app that I've made using a trial copy of Adobe Flash Builder 4.5.

Now, Flash Builder license has expired.

Is there any way to compile my code without using Flash Builder?

I read somewhere that there is a free compiler to do that. What about Flex? Is free? Maybe I can use my actionscript code with Flex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get free Flex SDK (which is used in Flash Builder). You can get it [here (4.5)](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4.5) or [here (4.1)](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4). Then read [official documentation about application compiler](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ffd.html) and apply these knowledges to your project.

And additional note. If you're student or uneployment you can get Flash Builder 4.5 Standard for free [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/free/).

Answer (score 6):

As the above answerer suggested, you can use the free Flex SDK. To go with this I would highly recommend flash develop (http://www.flashdevelop.org).

A fantastic tool for developing Flash based content without the flash IDE.

Comment: +100
I use it all days, for as3 projects, html/css, php, javascript, it's the ultimate free developing tool.

Comment: +100 here as well. Flash Builder might be good, but it's built on that POS Eclipse which makes me want to break my arms every time I'm forced to use it. Try FlashDevelop and see what an IDE is supposed to be

Comment: Can I use it to develop for Blackberry Playbook?

Comment: Nothing wrong with Eclipse once you learn how to use it--it's used by hundreds of thousands of Java developers every day, Flash Builder, devs using a number of other languages, and countless other 3rd party free and commercial "IDEs" for all kinds of different purposes.  Anyway, +1 for mentioning Flashdevelop--never heard of it before and it looks nice!!

Comment: I use FlashDevelop day in and out. HTML/CSS/JavaScript/PHP to AS2/AS3. I actually feel so weird when I need to resort back to the Flash IDE when I'm fixing other's code and they have it on the timeline. @VansFannel - Not sure about Blackberry Playbook, what language etc is it based around?

Comment: @Chris: My PlayBook app is an ActionScript 3.0 app.

Comment: Then you should be able to use Flash Develop